# Xubuntu 16.04 doesn't seem to remember any changes I make to the startup applications.

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, startup, dropbox, autostart

I recently installed Xubuntu 16.04 and I'm having trouble making any changes to the applications that startup when I log into my computer (from the Sessions and Startup menu). Any changes that I make in the "Application Autostart" tab, whether it is unchecking, editing, or removing are eventually reset to the defaults, and none of my changes are saved. Strangely enough, my changes will last for 1 or 2 reboots, but eventually they'll reset to the defaults (wtf right?). Changing the files manually in .config/autostart/ doesn't seem to make any difference either. Adding new startup apps is saved however.

For now I only care about changing the Dropbox autostart behavior. By default the Dropbox icon doesn't display correctly, and it looks something like this: https://s24.postimg.org/48gjnq6pt/dropbox.png . This is apparently a common issue for Xubuntu due to Dropbox starting in the indicator area rather in the notification area. I followed one of the suggested online solutions and created a new startup app with the command: "dbus-launch dropbox start -i", and disable the original. This worked temporarily, but due to the aforementioned issue, after a couple of reboots everything seems to be reset to the defaults and the wrong icon will be displayed again.

Can someone suggest a permanent solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you about Xubuntu not remembering startup apps changes. But you can try this to make Dropbox icon work-

Delete the custom startup entry you've made. If you've changed any Dropbbox installed files then reinstalled the app again. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open the terminal and run these commands:-

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

(gksu is probably already installed, carry on)

```
gksu mousepad /usr/bin/dropbox
```

Create a new line under the line "import os". Add the following text in the new line:

> os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] = ""

Save the file and reboot your PC.